# Chrome Extension - How to capture Scroll Position on open tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, scrolltop, message-passing

I currently capture scroll location on a tab by running it in a content script (see below) and injecting JQuery.

**Question** How do I apply scroll capture to all tabs open not just the current tab I'm on?
My try below works for just current tab.

Unsure how to iterate a for loop across all tabs since don't have access to chrome.tabs API in content script.  Am I approaching this wrong by constantly tracking scroll capture and should use a background.js to call a content_script function only on a certain event?

Thanks!

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "ScrollPosition",
"version": "1.0",
"background": {
"page": "background.html"
},
"content_scripts": [
{ "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
"js": ["jquery-1.11.1.min.js","content_script.js"]}
],
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "19": "images/icon19.png",
        "38": "images/icon38.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "windows",
    "<all_urls>",
    "chrome://favicon/",
]
}
```

**content_script.js**

```
var scrollPosition = 0;

function scrollPos() {
  $(document).scroll(function(){
    scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();  
    console.log('your scroll position is: '+scrollPosition);
  });
};

window.addEventListener("load", scrollPos);
```

Comment: You [guessed correctly](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). Only a content script can access the tab: running `$(this).scrollTop()` in a background page refers to the background page itself. Please try to split your question somehow: it's unclear what exactly should we be answering. Make it one problem at a time, you can always create more than one question.

Comment: @Xan Thanks for the quick response and clarified the question.  It seems the title was incorrect so updated that as well.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the background script to iterate over all tabs and inject custom scripts. You can iterate over all tabs in the background page using [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query). You can inject a script into a tab using chrome.tabs.executeScript. Now, you'll just need to [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the background script from your content script and you should be good to go.